Binance API: Incorrect Live Price Based on Timeframe Instead of Actual Current Price
I'm building a Discord bot that uses the Binance API to fetch the latest price of a cryptocurrency. However, I'm encountering an issue where the price returned by my bot is inconsistent. Specifically, the price varies based on the timeframe used to fetch historical data, instead of consistently returning the actual live price.
Here's a summary of what I'm doing:

Fetching Historical Data: Using get_realtime_data() to fetch OHLCV data for a given symbol and interval.

Fetching Latest Price: Using get_latest_price() to fetch the current live price.


Expected Behaviour
The bot should return the current live price of the cryptocurrency, regardless of the timeframe specified.
The Observed Behaviour
The bot returns different prices depending on the timeframe, and these prices do not match the actual live price from Binance.
# Data fetching methods in my data_collection.py
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def get_realtime_data(symbol, interval):
    # Fetch historical OHLCV data
    klines = client.get_klines(symbol=symbol, interval=interval, limit=100)
    # Processing data into DataFrame
    ...

def get_latest_price(symbol):
    # Fetch the latest price
    ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)
    return float(ticker['price'])

# Commands in main.py

import discord
import asyncio
import os
import time
import mplfinance as mpf
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from Data.data_collection import get_realtime_data  
from patterns.mainPatterns.signal_generator import SignalGenerator

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Retrieve Binance API keys and Discord token from environment variables
api_key = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_KEY')
api_secret = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_SECRET')
discord_token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

if not api_key or not api_secret or not discord_token:
    raise ValueError("One or more environment variables are missing.")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')


@bot.command(name='signal')
async def single_signal(ctx, symbol: str, interval: str):
    signal_generator = SignalGenerator(symbol, interval)
    try:
        current_data = get_realtime_data(symbol, interval)
        signals = signal_generator.generate_signals(current_data)
        response = "\n".join(signals) if signals else "No signals found."
        await ctx.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Error generating signals: {e}")

# Run the bot
bot.run(discord_token)




Pleas see minimal reproducible example code.
